# Flask not rendering template despite no errors

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask, jinja2

Flask is running and everything is working up to the point where my templated needs to be rendered but it's not doing anything.

So I have an HTML document that I created for a class project and now I am trying to link a MySQL database to retrieve some tables and put them onto the HTML document.  So far, I have sucessfully been able to convert the tables from MySQL to HTML syntaxed string in python using pandas:

```
for x in result:
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(x)).T
    df = pd.concat([df,df2])

pdTable = df.to_html()
```

However, when it comes to my app.py I import pdTable into app.py and try to render that into the HTML document using render_template but it seemingly does nothing:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import DBConnect
app = Flask(__name__)
print(DBConnect.pdTable)
@app.route('/')
def sqlTable():
    return render_template("indexCopy.html", pandas_table=DBConnect.pdTable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My indexCopy.html is in a folder(templates) in the directory that app.py is in,
and in my HTML document as far as I can tell this is how you're supposed to do the expression:

```
<div class="employeeTable">
    <a id="Employee"><h2>Employee</h2></a>
    {{ pandas_table|safe }}
</div>
```

I've been at this roadblock for several hours now and just cant figure this out.  Any help would be appreciated!

****UPDATE****

Discovered the issue.  It had to do with my confusion with how Flask apps work.  I initially thought that flask would overwrite the HTML the HTML file and that's why I got so confused, I was opening indexCopy.html believing it should have been overwritten.  I didn't realize you need to open the flask server ie. 127.0.0.1:5000. Once I figured that out everything was rendering as it should be. Hope this helps anyone who has a similar issue/confusion.

Comment: I believe the argument should be passed as a dictionary `{'pandas_table': DBConnect.pdTable}`, not as a kwarg `pandas_table=DBConnect.pdTable`.

Comment: Tried it but no difference I wonder if the sqlTable function isn't getting called for some reason?   `return render_template("indexCopy.html", {'pandas_table': DBConnect.pdTable})`

Comment: As a first debugging step, pass a hardcoded value like `{'pandas_table': 'hello'}` and see what that displays.

Comment: That didn't work either

Comment: Then that suggests the code is actually rendering a different html template file than you thought it was.